# Wordpress/CSS - a:link won't inherit color

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a site using Wordpress and I'm adding an email link in my footer. The color of the link text is now grey rather than white and won't change. I have the site built also as a stand along front-end site and this code works but it won't work on the wordpress version -

**footer.php**

```
<div class="col-md-6">        
                            <div id="email">
                                <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/footer_logo.png" style="width: 150px; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;">  
                                <p><a href="mailto:mikewhitehead00@aol.com" id="link">Email: hello@havoccreative.com</a></br>+971 (0)55 151 0491 or +971 (0)55 282 2114
                                </br>PO Box 769558, twofour54, Abu Dhabi</p>
                                <p>This website was design by us *pause for applause*</br> and built with his bare hands by Michael Whitehead.</br> &copy Havoc Creative 2017</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**style.css**

```
footer #link a:link, a:hover {
  color: inherit;

}
```

I've tried it a few different ways with the id at the end of the stye rule etc but still nothing. Not sure why the rule will apply in a standalone site but not on wordpress. I've also tried `!important` but still nothing. It needs to be white text like the rest of the footer text.

[image]

Comment: `#link a:link` looks incorrect. Did you mean `#link, a:link`?

Comment: Also make sure #email isn't setting different colors that are then correctly inherited.

Comment: Try not to use `!important`. Almost invariably bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: @sol Good spot - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect. It's basically targeting all `<a>` elements inside an element with ID link, inside `footer` elements, and also any `<a>` elements being hovered over. The problem is nothing to do with WordPress.

I'd replace your CSS with something simple like this:

```
footer #link, footer #link:hover { color: #ffffff; }
```